# Is it possible to see the source code history of an Azure alert?

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

Is it possible to see the source code history of an Azure alert?

For example, i would like to know when the Alert Condition's query was changed and mostly what was the previous query so i can revert it, even manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to view the changes in the alerts.

You can view the history of an Azure Alert using [Activity Log](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs)

[image]

Activity Logs provide data about the operations on a resource from the outside (the "control plane") like changing the alert queries and etc.,

From the image, you can see the actual JSON which will hold the values of your monitor alerts details.

You can also Export all these data into Event Hub, OMS after that you can query those logs.

Comment: Yes, Activity Log is the answer, however for me the operation name is "Scheduled query rule write" probably because my Alert Rule is a Log Alert